# How can I retrieve a file's size using the HTML5 FileSystem interface?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-filesystem

How might I learn the size of a file located in a local filesystem exposed through the HTML5 API?

I'm expecting something along the lines of,

```
 fileSystem.root.getFile(path, { create: false }, function (fileEntry) {
       //    fileEntry.size - ????????

        });
```

...to be available, but haven't found anything like it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to call:

```
fileEntry.getMetadata(function(metadata) { 
    alert(metadata.size); // or do something more useful with it...
});
```

See the specifications for the filesystem [Entry interface](http://www.w3.org/TR/file-system-api/#the-entry-interface) and [Metadata interface](http://www.w3.org/TR/file-system-api/#the-metadata-interface) for details.